# jQuery AJAX Processing Response - Access Control/Allow Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an AJAX request that calls a URL when a button is clicked - this is all working successfully and I can confirm the GET request is made by checking the logs of the server where the request is made.

When I enter this URL into a browser I get a simple response like this:

```
Authentication accepted 
ActionID = ABC12345677890
```

I'm trying to show that response in my HTML (or an error if there was one). Here's my script:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.server.com/callback.php?type=makecall",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

When I click the button to make the call the GET request is made but I get this in my HTML:

```
There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: 0
```

Checking the console logs I see these entries:

```
[Error] Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (callback.php, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.server.com/callback.php?type=makecall due to access control checks.
```

This is my first time working with AJAX requests to an external server so not sure what is going on error and why I'm getting an error when the GET request was successful? I'm testing this locally and calling the page via the http://localhost syntax.

Comment: you need to understand CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mostly CORS issues Access should allowed from server side i.e allow-access-header property but although you can go through following

If I understood it right you are doing an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)  to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is Using [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy. Quoted from [Cross-Origin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) XMLHttpRequest:

Answer (score 0):

I did need to learn about CORS and set the response headers on the server. These sites came in handy:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
https://enable-cors.org
http://www.test-cors.org